# Information.Gain error for Random Forest with MLR Package in R

Tags: r, random-forest, mlr

Below is the complete code which I m trying to execute with MLR Library in R for a Random forest to check "information.gain" and "chi-square" values. 
My DV is sales "quantity" which is continuous.

```
>>traintask_1 <- makeRegrTask(data=finaltrain,target="quantity")
>>
im_feat <- generateFilterValuesData(traintask_1, method = c("information.gain","chi.squared"))
```

Facing this below Error issue while running `generateFilterValuesData()`

```
>Error in .jcall("weka/filters/Filter", "Lweka/core/Instances;", "useFilter",  : 
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A duplicate bin range was detected. Try increasing the bin range precision
```

Please, someone, help me with this error!!

Comment: Can you post a complete example that allows to reproduce the problem please?

Comment: Looks like a Java error thrown by the `FSelector` pkg? Problably a local problen on your machine. Try the `FSelectorRcpp` method in the `featsel_praznik` branch - 100 x times fast and not Java dependent. Should be in the `master` branch in a few days.